# Chain rule for paths from $ I \subset \mathbb{R} $ to $ \mathbb{R ^ m} $

Tags: real-analysis

let $ \phi: I \to J $  be differentiable at a point $ a\in I $ and $ f: J \to \mathbb{R^m}$ a differentiable path at point $ b = \phi(a) $. So the path $f \circ \phi: I \to \mathbb {R ^ m} $ is differentiable in the
point $a$ and $(f \circ \phi)'(a) =  \phi'(a)f'(b)$.

I tried to make a test using the coordinate functions of $f$ and $g$, but I want to know if there is a more convenient and simple way for this demonstration.

Comment: Do you mean $b=\phi(a)$?

Comment: Yes of course. Excuse me

Comment: You want $f\circ \phi.$

Comment: Exactly. Given the assumptions I want to prove that the composition $ f \circ \phi $ is differentiable in $ a $